iOS App Crashes After Updating to .NET 8.0: Any Solutions?
I have a time tracking app built with .NET Maui. After updating from .NET 7.0 to .NET 8.0, the following issue started to occur: when opening the application, if it takes too long to perform an action, it closes. If I open it and perform an action, when I try to perform the action again, it closes.
In some cases, this exception appears:

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'

in the AppDelegate.
I tried updating all dependencies and even installing some previews, but without success. This occurs only on the iOS platform. The other platforms, Android and Windows, were already on version .NET 8.0.

Please show us some code, which generates the error and details about where the error occures. Or even better provide the minimal reproducible example
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

You can check if the dependencies in your project already support .net8.

Or you can try to set breakpoint at the relevant code of the operation you performed to view detailed error information.

Does this error occur on a default MAUI project?  From the error, you may first figure out what exactly is null, and which line causes the issue.

Are you using an iOS-specific API in your project? Does this issue also appear in the default project?
